# Dax Time Intelligence how to calculate current week Sales

Tags: powerbi, dax

I Would like to to calculate this  week sales  using DAX(Current week sales) (Latest week) Starting from Monday to the latest day of the current week/latest week.

I have attached pbix file
https://app.box.com/s/ah11tcvbq45rlc5pujunxkfloyd4x7cu

Total Sales $392[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A simple WTD measure would look something like this:

```
Sales WTD = 
    calculate(sum(CountrySales[Sale]),
                    filter(all('Date'), 'Date'[Date] <= max('Date'[Date]) 
                                     && 'Date'[WeekNum] = max('Date'[WeekNum])))
```

You can read all about the [calculate](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dax/calculate-function-dax) function online, watch [videos](https://www.sqlbi.com/tv/dax-the-calculate-function/), and there's a whole chapter devoted to it in [The Definitive Guide to Dax](https://www.sqlbi.com/books/the-definitive-guide-to-dax/).

Comment: Thanks @David Browne, just quick question, how can I show the latest week? data (i.e week 32 data only?)

Comment: Use a filter or slicer on the week number.  And if you always want to show the latest week, add a column to your calendar table that marks all dates belonging to the latest week, and refresh it daily.

Comment: Much appreciated  @David Browne, any chance you advice on Month to date MTD, Quarter to date QTD and YTD please, please pbix link with dummy data.  https://app.box.com/s/6ctcewpl99axquosbsjwcct5ikdgvuer

Comment: It's the same pattern.  You just need MonthNumber and QuarterNumber columns on your calendar.  It's convenient to have the year included too, so you can keep the comparison simple.

Answer (score 1):

Create a new visual table, drag your WeekNum and Sale in the table. Select the combobox of the Weeknum and select: Don't summarize. End result as below:

[image]